# Pythonic way to include or exclude a part of a string depending on a conditional value

Tags: python, string

I have genomic data, and depending on the value of `ref` (it can either equal `'b37'` or `'hg19'`), the command I use will either have a `chr` at the beginning or have nothing at the beginning (e.g. `chr2` vs. `2`).

Right now, I'm doing it like this: `min('chr', ref).strip('b37') + <chromosome_number>`.

This way is rather... creative, I'd say, and it wouldn't work if the name of the variables and such didn't work out as it did.  I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to do this that still reserves the condense, "pythonic" form of my way.

Comment: `str.strip('b37')` doesn't do what you think it does. It will remove any `b`, `3` and `7` characters from the start and end *in any order*.

Comment: Can you provide more detail/examples about your input, processing, and desired output?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No it is doing what I think it is doing. That's what I mean when I say "it wouldn't work if the name of the variables and such didn't work out as it did", e.g. if `'chr'` or `'hg19'` had a `'b'` in it.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
('chr' if ref == 'hg19' else '') + <chromosome_number>
```

Comment: I was hoping there were something like this. Good old python coming in clutch.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using "conditional-indexing" because the boolean values `False` and `True` are equivalent numerically to `0` and `1`.

```
['', 'chr'][ref == 'hg19'] + <chromosome_number>
```

This can be easily extended to handle cases where there's more than two possibilities from which to choose.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that you can use `True` or `False` to `__getitem__`! I suppose to generalize if there are n>2 options for `ref` one could simply use a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, use a dictionary like this: `{'chr': 'hg19', 'foo': 'bar'}.get(ref, '')`.